# Can't open a .dbproj file from VSTS DB Edition

Tags: visual-studio, dbproj

The title says everything. I'm using Visual Studio Team System 2008 Database Edition and I just can't open any database project. I get the following error message:

> '..' cannot be opened because its
>   project type (.dbproj) is not
>   supported by this version of the
>   application. To open it, please use a
>   version that supports this type of
>   project.

Does this ever happen to you?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just found the answer to my problem [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/62a20091-d61d-49c1-bb19-ac935055dc83). It worked fine, after executing the following command:

```
devenv /resetskippkgs
```

May be it'll help someone one day :)